# How to set multiple Django site on VPS using Apache?

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have Deploy a Django application on VPS using Apache and mod_wsgi. Without a Domain name. One can access the site just by typing IP address on browser. Now I have another application I want to configure this second application  with similar IP address, how can I set this.

So that if some one can access both the site just by typing

```
xx.xxx.xxx.63/app1
or 
xx.xxx.xxx.63/app2
```

On browser.. bellow is my "000-default.conf" file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    Alias /static /home/myproject/DATAPLO/static
    <Directory /home/myproject/DATAPLO/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>


    <Directory /home/myproject/trytable>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/home/myproject:/home/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup myproject
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/myproject/trytable/wsgi.py

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: Why do they need to be separate sites? Can they not just be separate applications under the same Django project?

Comment: These are two totally different sites rather two application withing a single site

Comment: Have you checked out the mod_wsgi documentation which describes this? http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/configuration-guidelines.html

Comment: Also suggest you read the documentation on how to use Python virtual environments as not use the preferred configuration. http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/configuration-guidelines.html

Comment: And for good measure when you find requests going to the wrong application, read http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/requests-running-in-wrong-django.html